# react app looks different from one in w3school and other tutorials

Tags: reactjs, default

this is the default app code in w3school or other courses in their directory (/myfirstreact/src/App.js:) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component{
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <p>
                Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
              </p>
              <a
                className="App-link"
                href="https://reactjs.org"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                Learn React
              </a>
            </header>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

and this is mine :

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i still didn't change anything and i cant follow the course with this different code 
and even when i manually type the default code i get lots of errors !!!!
can someone please tell me how can i solve this ??

Comment: To be a beginner follow https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/ or https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Please include error messages in your question

Comment: If you are going to learn libraries like React, you should first have enough JavaScript knowledge so that you can follow explanations. Then by looking at the differences in the code, you should easily understand that it is fine to use classes as components or functions as components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook introduces Hooks in their 16.8 version and it works with only functional components so in some of the tutorials they have started implementing a new hook API so that's why you found functional components .w3schools have not updated their tutorials for Hook API.

I suggest you to start with HOOK API because it is easy to understand and also there is less memory leak compare to class base components and they solve many issues which was there in class base components.

You can refer below link for hook startup:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You should put the errors here, but I see a big difference between the codes.

The w3school code is using a Class:

```
class App extends Component {
```

And you are using a function:

```
function App() {
```

Both codes are OK.

So... I need to know how are using the App component. It should be something like this:

```
import App from './App.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If you are doing the same, try to put all your code in condesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) and share it here!

Comment: i didnt type any of this codes and my question is why after creating a default react app using ( npx create-react app)   i get different source code than the ones in tutorials ?

Comment: Maybe you have an updated version of create-react-app than the used on the tutorial!